# Asynchronous hierarchy

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

If I had an asynchronous method that contained an asynchronous method and a none asynchronous method in the parameters.

Which method would run first?

Example:

```
await ExampleMethod(
            Func<Task>: await Example.SomeMethod(), 
            Func<IEnumerable<T>> Example.SomeOtherMethod()
            );
```

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: It runs fine on local, but not on live environment

Comment: "Fine"? What does that mean?

Comment: As in the SomeMethod runs first on local, but in live env it doesn't seem to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which method would run first?

There's nothing magic about asynchronous method invocations. They [start executing synchronously, just like any other method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (as I describe on my blog). Also, asynchrony doesn't impact the order of argument evaluation at all.

So, this code:

```
await ExampleMethod(await Example.SomeMethod(), Example.SomeOtherMethod());
```

is essentially the same as this code:

```
var parameter1 = await Example.SomeMethod();
var parameter2 = Example.SomeOtherMethod();
await ExampleMethod(parameter1, parameter2);
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that has helped me a lot. Thanks for being more in depth about it